# What is the most effective way to create a reference to this HTML element using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

If I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

What is the most effective way (mainly in terms of performance) to create a reference to the <iframe> DOM element? I'm using something like the following:

```
var element = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
```

IIRC, though, getElementsByTagName can be a slow performer. Is that not an issue since there's only one element within the <div id="container"> anyway?

Is there a more concise, and/or better-performing way to get the <iframe> here? It's safe to say that it will always be the only child of <div id="container">, but not always the only <iframe> on the page.

Comment: What about selectors? `var element = document.querySelector("#container iframe");`

Comment: That isn't standard JavaScript is it?

Comment: "querySelector() and querySelectorAll() is supported in Firefox 3.1+, IE8+ (only in IE8 standards mode), and Safari 3.1+."

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the suggestion, Steve, and the follow-up, Skilldrick. That's not well-supported enough for this project, but it sounds like it could make life easier as the importance of legacy browser support diminishes in the coming years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put an ID on the iframe and reference it with `gEBI`. If you're not noticing any latency with `gEBTN` then I suggest keeping the code the same as is, and yes providing a context for `gEBTN` helps.

Comment: Thanks, meder! For this project, I'd rather not add an ID to the <iframe>, as this is a widget intended for use on any Web page and I'd like to avoid even the minute chance of a conflict. The ID "container" will be actually be something specified by the owner of the page hosting the widget. Good to know that using gEBTN in context improves performance.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you wont notice the performance. If you would however do `document.getElementsByTagName` you would probably notice it as it has to walk the entire DOM tree.

Remember that it´s not always about performance, in many cases it´s better to have clear readable code then a *perl-one-liner* that will look like jibberish to anyone, including you, when they revisit it after 2 weeks.

If you can add an `id` attribute to the `iframe` element that would of course be the best solution as Meder says.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it seems it is all right with code. I think you can forget about performance for such simple javascript code.